# Fitting data with integral functions

Tags: python, integration, curve-fitting

I am trying to fit some data with a with a function that contains an integral using `scipy.optimize.curve_fit` (example code given below). I guess I have two question, 1) is this the best method to use for fitting a function of an integral, the majority of worked examples I have seen just fit simple models. 2) when run the fit, I only ever get the values I state explicitly as the starting points, which are most certainly not the best fits, and I am at a loss why this happens. Any insight would be much appreciated!

```
import numpy as np 
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import scipy.integrate as integrate
import csv


x = np.array([  4.3,   8. ,  12. ,  16. ,  20. ,  24. ])
y = np.array([ 1.,  0.98863022,  0.94294947,  0.9060894 ,  0.83959439,
    0.81545772])


def Bfitfunc(T, we, wh):
        ph = lambda w: (np.exp(-we * w**2)-np.exp(-wh * w**2))/np.tanh(0.5 * w/T)
        phi = integrate.quad(ph, 0, 10)
        return np.exp(- 0.5 * phi[0])


vcurve = np.vectorize(Bfitfunc,  excluded=set([1]))

best_vals, covar = curve_fit(Bfitfunc, x, y, p0 = np.array([0.001,0.001]))
```

Comment: Could you please add some sample data instead of using the data from a file?

Comment: I guess this should work fine. `np.curve_fit` will use `scipy.optimize.least_squares` in the background.

Comment: Having abandoned the built in algorithms and coding my own least mean squared I realise that one of the issues was that the their is no unique value for we and wh that minimises the error. This might explain why the fitting algorithm was not working correctly

Comment: `temps` and `vis` are missing

Comment: Is `vcurve` used anywhere?